# Which of these three op amps should I choose for my low frequency filter?

Tags: operational-amplifier, low-pass, sallen-key

I want to design a lowpass filter-4th order Bessel, so two Sallen-Key low-pass circuits in cascade with a cutoff frequency of 200Hz. I  need to choose the op amps for it.

I have these 3 op amps to choose from:

- MCP6004
- TL084
- LM324

A quick google search tells me that MCP6004 is best used for analog filters and the TL084 for AC-DC conversions which is a thing I will plan to do.

I tried to find data sheets for TL084 and all I found [was this](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl084.pdf?ts=1635777202664&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fstore%252Fti%252Fen%252Fp%252Fproduct%252F%253Fp%253DTL084CN%2526keyMatch%253DTL084CN%2526tisearch%253Dsearch-everything%2526usecase%253DOPN).

[image]

There's like a TL084A,B,C and beyond so I'm not even sure what I am looking at, all I know is that I have can have a TL084. I don't know what the B and C versions are.

In the very top left of that link Ihave the main features that I think are valid for all models of TL084, it has a very high slew rate. I tested that in LTspice and compared it to LM324 and the results show me that when I put a square wave input at a TL084 op amp I get a square wave but when I do it to a LM324 I get a trapezoid. Because my circuit has a cutoff frequency of 200 Hz I think that any ampop unity-gain bandwidth can do well here, so I will perhaps exclude the LM324.

For the MCP6004 I got its sheet and found this:

[image]

All the input bias currents and input voltage offset are very low.

For the TL084 I got confused reading the sheet.

[image]

I found this in page 16.  I'mnot sure if that is for the TL084 as in the image it has a X in it. If that's the case then the input bias currents and input voltage offset are also very low.

What should I choose?

Comment: I dont understand why this question is closed, he clearly is asking for help to understand what parameters he should look at for his filter. This is not off topic.

Comment: You choose based on the expected performance of your circuit. You haven't stated that at all. Noise, offsets, out-of-band performance, power rail versatility, temperature range, overall gain, input impedance, output drive capability, slew rate and probably some more things that just are not covered in this: *lowpass filter-4th order Bessel*. Next asking someone to choose based on 3 offerings means that you are presuming one of the 3 is the overall best choice in all op-amps in the world. This will outdate answers rapidly. Not accepting answers is also something you should look at.